# What would be the best approach to process 10 B rows of data on a daily basis to create variables (calculated columns)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, architecture, bigdata, data-processing

Imagine you have a historical data and every day a couple of million rows of data gets added to it. There is a need to process the whole data on a daily basis and update variables. How would you approach this problem using Big data platform?

Happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: What "Big data platform" did you have in mind? HDFS will happily store your data, and Spark will happily process it

Comment: I was thinking to have Hortonworks as Big Data Platform. But the challenge is that I need to perform the aggregation process on the whole dataset on a daily basis.

Comment: Why exactly is that a challenge? Setup a daily process to do whatever you want. Hortonworks provides Oozie for this purpose

Comment: Size of the data, currently using RDBMS platform it takes almost 2 days to refresh and do aggregation on a weekly basis. The goal is to this on a daily basis using Hadoop platform. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you want fast aggregations, I might recommend Solr or Elasticsearch instead. But, sure, any distributed processing framework will be quicker than a single-threaded table scan.

Answer (score 1):

Try very hard not to reprocess the whole 10B rows...  I don't know what exactly you are looking for in that large of a dataset, but there is very likely a statistical model in which you can keep summary information, and just reprocess the incremental against that.

cricket_007 is right though, HDFS and Spark are likely your first tools of choice.

Comment: It is more like having a billion rows of raw data and the business requirement is to perform aggregation process on data on a daily basis for modelling purposes.